# Vaadin - aligning elements in CSSLayout

Tags: java, css, layout, vaadin

I got a CSSlayout where is three elements like label, label and bordereless button (X) used like icon. I have set setSizeUndefined and I would like to have a layout like: Label with extra space, because size of the label can be something like 0 px to 200px. Then I need an another label and then aligned to far right delete button, like X. I really can't do that, annoying. This should work in mobile devices as well so I think that fixed sizes are not so good idea. Float right is not working with button icon...

```
<div class="v-csslayout v-layout v-widget">
    <div class="v-label v-widget uploadedRow-fileName v-label-uploadedRow-fileName v-label-undef-w">logo.jpg</div>
    <div class="v-label v-widget uploadedRow-description v-label-uploadedRow-description v-label-undef-w">Description1</div>
        <div style="width: 1px;" id="logo.jpg" class="v-button v-widget icon-only v-button-icon-only borderless v-button-borderless uploadedRow-deleteButton v-button-uploadedRow-deleteButton v-has-width" role="button" tabindex="0"><span class="v-button-wrap"><span class="v-icon FontAwesome"></span><span class="v-button-caption"></span></span></div>
   </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you have 1px width for the button? Seems unnecessary. I suggest you use flexbox to align the items if you can. If you can’t (because of browser support), then absolute positioning might work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a float right to the close button.

```
<div style="width: 1px; float: right;" id="logo.jpg" class="v-button v-widget icon-only v-button-icon-only borderless v-button-borderless uploadedRow-deleteButton v-button-uploadedRow-deleteButton v-has-width" role="button" tabindex="0"><span class="v-button-wrap"><span class="v-icon FontAwesome"></span><span class="v-button-caption"></span></span></div>
```

Comment: like I said in question that it is not working, I don't know why. .v-button-uploadedRow-deleteButton{
   margin-top: -1px;
          float:right;}

Comment: I tried to add new horizontal-layout and but the button in it. it is working somehow with fixed size, but not responsively.